# Is it possible to obtain the Uniform distribution as the difference of two independent random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, convolution

Is it possible to have two independent random variables X,Y with identical distribution, such that  $X-Y \sim \text{Uniform}[a,b]$? I am almost certain that is not, but maybe I am overlooking something?

Comment: No. Hint: characteristic functions. What did you try?

Comment: @Did I never have seen this before and I just gave it a go. I can see why this cannot be done why $a\neq -b$, but not generally. Why can't there be a characteristic function $f$ such that $f(t)f(-t) = \frac{\sin (bt)}{itb}$? am i missing something obvious?

Comment: First $f(t)f(-t)$ would not be what you write but $\sin(bt)/(bt)$. Second, $f(-t)=\overline{f(t)}$ hence...

Comment: @Did yeah. i see, very nice. thanks again.

Comment: @Did: I get $\frac{E(e^{itX})}{E(e^{itY})}=\frac{e^{itb}-e^{-itb}}{2itb} =\frac{\text{sin}(bt)}{bt}$ and therefore I cannot obtain two identically distributed random variables. Is that the argument that you're suggesting?

Comment: I do not see a argument in your comment. // Note that $E(e^{it(X-Y)})$ is not what you write but $E(e^{itX})E(e^{-itY})$.

Comment: Yes. I see my mistake. However, I do not see how to develop the argument from there on. Can you give me a hint? (Sorry, I'm quite new to these topics. If you can recommend a good textbook on the topic I'm also very grateful.)

Comment: Initially I thought one could make an argument using the convolution formula: $f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(w)f_{-Y}(z-w)\text{d}w=\frac{1}{2b} $. But now I am very curious how it would work with the characteristic function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. and that $Z=X-Y$ is uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$.

Then $(Y,X)$ is distributed like $(X,Y)$ hence $Y-X$ is distributed like $X-Y$. Since $Y-X=-Z$ is uniformly distributed on $(-b,-a)$, this proves that $(a,b)=(-b,-a)$. Thus $a=-b$ and the characteristic function $\varphi_Z$ of $Z$ is such that $\varphi_Z(t)=\sin(bt)/(bt)$ for every $t$.

By independence of $X$ and $Y$, $E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itZ})=E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX})E(\mathrm e^{-\mathrm itY})$. Furthermore, since $Y$ is distributed like $X$, $\varphi_Z(t)=\varphi_X(t)\varphi_X(-t)=|\varphi_X(t)|^2\geqslant0$ for every $t$. But obviously, $\varphi_Z(t)<0$ for some well chosen $t$, say $t=3\pi/(2b)$, which is absurd.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong - just a minor quibble. Isn't $\sin(\pi) = 0$ or am I missing something? So just taking $t = \frac{3\pi}{2b}$ should fix the argument. Anyway, even if I'm right, this is just a minor point. Thanks for the very nice answer.

Comment: @AnlamK Indeed! Corrected. Thanks for the heads up.